# How do I access google cloud storage from local python app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am able to access gcs when my app is deployed to gae, but I would like to access gcs from my local machine during development. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the traceback i get when i try to open a file on gcs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Downloads/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Documents/fallsafety-dataflow/preprocess/main.py", line 74, in get
    self.to_csv()
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Documents/fallsafety-dataflow/preprocess/main.py", line 41, in to_csv
    compressed_flo    = gcs.open(read_filepath, 'r')
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Documents/fallsafety-dataflow/preprocess/lib/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py", line 103, in open
    offset=offset)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Documents/fallsafety-dataflow/preprocess/lib/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 249, in __init__
    errors.check_status(status, [200], path, resp_headers=headers, body=content)
  File "/Users/alvinsolidum/Documents/fallsafety-dataflow/preprocess/lib/cloudstorage/errors.py", line 132, in check_status
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
NotFoundError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 404.
Path: '/fallsafety-test-general/apple-watch/continuous/active/54d0044919e92b0c00c29555-29391CEA593C4D798A1EA08BD23DA47E-0002-continuous.csv.gz'.
Request headers: None.
Response headers: {'date': 'Mon, 29 Aug 2016 23:15:49 GMT', 'server': 'Development/2.0', 'connection': 'close'}.
Body: ''.
Extra info: None.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, it looks like you're using the appengine-gcs-client for Python. When running on the local development server, the client defaults to using a local, fake version of GCS (see the response header that says "Server: Development/2.0"?). I'm guessing that you're looking for a real GCS object that you haven't uploaded to the local fake.

You can get around this either by uploading the object in question as part of your server initialization, using a different library (gcloud-python is really nice), or disabling the local fake, which you could do by setting the SERVER_SOFTWARE environment variable:

```
# Logic for whether to use local fake is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/f9dbbd43ec431f739aa33a44cf24d32a19579f33/python/src/cloudstorage/common.py#L387
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Development (remote_api)/1.0'
```

Comment: I can not believe how bad their documentation is.
Why go through all the trouble of authenticating with a service account locally if it's going to use a fake storage anyways?
Why is there no mention of this "fake gcs server" in the docs?
Why is there no mention of `SERVER_SOFTWARE` in the docs?
Do they really expect us to read the code to understand how to use their software?

Comment: I can't believe how much time I just wasted trying to figure this out. thanks for the tip.